# Emulate an LDAP-Authentication based on IMAP

Tags: imap, authentication, ldap

**Is there a way to emulate a LDAP-Server while in the background authenticate against an IMAP-Server?**

Explanation:
I'm running some services in in our local network like Git, SVN, Seafile and potentially more. Some run on Windows some on Linux servers. It is really tidious to manage the user accounts for all those services seperatly. They usually offer authentication against an LDAP-Server but I do not really want to set one up because, I do not need all the features. I have only around ten accounts and do not need groups etc.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The *authentication* part is certainly possible: a custom-written LDAP server could handle `bind` requests (both IMAP and LDAP use the same SASL authentication) and always return no results to all searches.

If the clients use SASL PLAIN authentication, it would be enough to run an empty OpenLDAP along with Cyrus `saslauthd`, which supports a "rimap" authentication method which checks the passwords against an IMAP server.

**However, most likely that will not be enough** – LDAP is primarily a *user directory*, with authentication just as a side effect, and programs will expect to also obtain user information from it. *That* cannot be retrieved over IMAP in any way.

Also, if the clients use "simple bind" authentication, OpenLDAP *itself* will expect the user entries to exist within the LDAP directory (with specially formatted passwords that tell it to use `saslauthd` again).

My suggestion here is to use each tool for its intended purpose. IMAP is a mail access protocol; it is not in *any* way a good authentication protocol, and IMAP servers just don't make good user directory servers. On the other hand, that's just the kind of job LDAP is made for.

In other words: *Do* create a LDAP directory – nobody cares if it's just 10 users – and configure the IMAP server to get user information from LDAP as well. By avoiding weird backwards setups, you will save yourself a lot of pain in the future.